# Make image SlideShow and text by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I want make a jquery slideshow with show text(each text in title tag `<img>`) in following image without use plugin, i tried as: (it doesn't work [i should use of class `div.mediumCell` for tag `img` and text it])

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pzyxk/

```
$('.fadein .mediumCell:not(:first)').hide();
setInterval(showNext, 3000);

function showNext() {
    $('div#caption').remove();
    var current = $('.fadein :first-child');
    var next = current.next('.mediumCell');

    current.fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).appendTo('.fadein');
    })

    caption(next);
    $(next).next(".mediumCell").andSelf().fadeIn()
};

function caption(element) {
    $('<div class="mediumCell"/>').hide().html($(element).attr("alt")).insertAfter($(element)).fadeIn();
};
```

How is fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For you html are:

```
<div class="presentaion">
    <span class="caption"></span>
    <img src="http://www.ct4me.net/images/Showing_Grade_1.jpg" width="100px" title="MyTitle_1" />
    <img src="http://www.ct4me.net/images/dmbtest.gif" width="100px" title="MyTitle_2" />
    <img src="http://celticevolution.com/images/test-201.gif" width="100px" title="MyTitle_3" />
</div>
```

And JS are:

```
show($('div.presentaion img:first')); // show first slide

function show(el) {
    el.parents('div.presentaion').find('img').hide(); // hide all slide
    el.prev('span.caption:first').html(el.attr('title')); // show caption from title
    el.show(); // show image

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (typeof(el.next('img:first')) != 'undefined') {
            show(el.next('img:first')); // set timeout to show next
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Edited [here, jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzyxk/12/)

Comment: But you changed my code) Try to not change the code, and reformat your html to be as required `// requires div.presentation with <img> in it and span caption before all <img>`

Comment: edited, now it works, there was en error in `setTimeout()`, sorry.

Comment: If it's possible - give any feedback to know about it works or not for you.